# Can I get the values from the "GET" parameters as array?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I can get data from url like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/?key=003
```

I show output as Json. This is **view.py**

```
def page(request):

    key = request.GET['key']

    data=Device.objects.get(key=key)
    print(key)
   
    data = {
        "open": data.open,
        "close": data.close,
    }

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

I try to get many value in same time like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/?key=003&key=004
```

In terminal it show output like this.

```
[22/Mar/2022 15:19:22] "GET /page/?key=003&key004 HTTP/1.1" 200 64
003
```

The output show 003 only. Can I get the values from the "GET" parameters as array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one parameter with the same key. Just do this:

```
key = request.GET.getlist('key')
```

And you will get an array with the key values.